# Airport Extreme with G4, iMac and iPad?

Tags: airport, airport-extreme

I just purchased a new iMac running Lion 10.7.3 ( 2.7 GHz with i5 ) and a 16 Gig Wifi iPad, I also have a G4 867 Power PC running Tiger 10.4.11.
Currently I have a Linksys 2.4 Ghz 802.11g router connected to a cable modem and my G4. This makes up my small WiFI network. It runs well, but I also know that 802.11g and the 2.4GHz are older standards.
I have been looking at getting the Airport Extreme, but I am not sure if I will be able to set it up because the system requirements for the Extreme 10.5.7 for set up and admin.
I was wondering if I could do the set up on my iMac and then unplug and plug it into the G4 ? or perhaps you fine folks could offer up a better solution.

Thanks
John

P.S The G4 does not have a Network card or any Wifi capability, I would like to keep it connected to the network with an ethernet cable, but I am not sure if a WiFi card or USB adapter would be cost effective. But I am open to any ideas.

Comment: There are lots of benefits of getting a router that has two radios ( one for 2.4ghz and one for 5.0ghz ) many of those reasons are connected to performance and the lack of interferance on the 5.ghz band.  Furthermore updates to the Airport Extreme product itself means even with a single radio support its more powerful and can provide better speeds because its say 3x3 instead of 3x2.  Of course Linksys also have the exact same devices with dual radio support, there is nothing special about the Airport Extreme, except its built-in seemless support for Apple products.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to transfer a lot of data from machine to machine within your house, upgrading the wireless will do very little as it is highly likely that unless you are on Fiber/fast internet, the wireless g throughput will be more than your internet, so, even if you upgraded to N, there will not actually be a benefit to using it.

As for setting it up, it should be very easy / Ios devices have a built in setup that you can do. You should be able to do what you want, I just wouldn't do it if you don't have problems (speed/reliability e.t.c.).